# Casting from shared_ptr<void> to shared_ptr<T> and back?

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

I need help understanding how to cast from `shared_ptr<void>` to `shared_ptr<T>` and back, while keeping the underlying reference count and pointer intact.

How would I go about casting between these two types in both directions?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  My IDE (VS2015) doesn't have these casts available to it for some reason

Comment: Make sure to include `<memory>` and try again. VS2015 has these casts. If it doesn't work, share your attempt.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - ah, my mistake.  I assumed I had already included it to get the shared pointers but I was wrong.  Thank you

Comment: `shared_ptr<void>` think twice if you really need it.